# Why is adding music to an iTunes library so slow?

Tags: itunes, music

Adding new mp3s to my iTunes library, either by dragging and dropping or via file dialogs, can take up to 3 minutes *per song*, especially when accessing a network drive or NAS (the same files would copy in seconds). I am on Mac OS X Yosemite right, but I've also seen long times on Windows. My library is about 80,000 songs.

Is this a result of the size of my library? What happens behind the scenes as part of this process? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: Not enough detail about your setup to answer?  You mention NAS, you don't mention how anything is connected.  Is wifi involved?

Comment: First guess is network bottleneck.

Comment: The **worst** performance is over wireless to NAS, but it can also be bad locally. Here's an additional piece of info: each successive folder add is faster, as long as iTunes is kept open (even across days). It is almost as if each load is causing some sort of caching of the database that is making it faster in the future. 

I'm just wondering if there is a workaround to take advantage of this effect.

Comment: One other point: the iTunes itl db file (as well as xml etc.) is local. Only the music files being added can be on the NAS.